# Missing SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder in System.Data.SqlServerCE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I can't find this class in the specified namespace, only reason I can imagine is that I'm referencing System.Data.SqlServerCE is 3.5 version while should be 4.0 version.

However I just reinstalled it (downloaded from microsoft website) and still is 3.5.

I really can't understand why this class is missing, any helps appreciated on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you adding a reference from a .NET 4 or .NET 3.5 project?

Comment: .net 4 project, but I can't find any available reference to .net 4 dll, maybe an installer problem that didn't copy the dll correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself, infact it looks like I had some problems with installation.
After uninstalled everything related to sql server compact and reinstalled only 4.0 server, the dll 4.0 is addable to my project and I can effectivly use SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.